# one side with texture other coloured yellow XNA C#

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

This time I have this cube made of triangles. My code assignes texture to each triangle. How to change the code so only one wall will be left as texture and other will be painted yellow?

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        private float angle = .9f;
        private float SecondAngle = -1f;

        //MyVertexFormat struct to go here

        struct MyVertexFormat
        {
            private Vector3 position;
            private Vector2 texCoord;
            public MyVertexFormat(Vector3 position, Vector2 texCoord)
            {
                this.position = position;
                this.texCoord = texCoord;
            }

            //Add VertexDeclaration here

        public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new
    VertexDeclaration(
    new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
    VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3,
    VertexElementFormat.Vector2,
    VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0));
        }

        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        GraphicsDevice device;

        Effect effect;
        Matrix viewMatrix;
        Matrix projectionMatrix;
        VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
        Vector3 cameraPos;
        Texture2D wallTexture;





        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 500;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            Window.Title = "HLSL Start";

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            device = GraphicsDevice;
            wallTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("wall");
            effect = Content.Load<Effect>("Effect1"); 
            SetUpVertices(); 
            SetUpCamera();
        }



        private void SetUpVertices()
        {
            MyVertexFormat[] vertices = new MyVertexFormat[36];
            //Back
            vertices[0] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
           new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[1] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, -1),
           new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[2] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, -1),
           new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));


            vertices[3] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[4] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[5] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, -1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));

            //Bottom
            vertices[6] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, 1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[7] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[8] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));


            vertices[9] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[10] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, 1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[11] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, 1),
           new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));

            //Top
            vertices[12] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, 1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[13] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[14] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));


            vertices[15] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[16] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[17] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));

            //Right side
            vertices[18] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[19] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[20] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, 1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));


            vertices[21] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[22] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[23] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, -1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));

            //Left side
            vertices[24] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, 1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[25] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));
            vertices[26] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, 1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));

            vertices[29] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, 1),
            new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[28] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));
            vertices[27] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));

            //Front
           vertices[30] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, 1, 1),
           new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));
           vertices[31] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
           new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));
           vertices[32] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, 1),
           new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));


           vertices[33] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, -1, 1),
           new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f));
           vertices[34] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(-1, -1, 1),
           new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f));
           vertices[35] = new MyVertexFormat(new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
           new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f));

            vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device,
                MyVertexFormat.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Length,
            BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            vertexBuffer.SetData(vertices);




        }

        private void SetUpCamera()
        {
            cameraPos = new Vector3(0, 5, 6);
            viewMatrix =  Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPos, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
            projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 200.0f);
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();




            viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle)) *
                         Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(SecondAngle)) *
                         viewMatrix;

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            device.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1.0f, 0);

            effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["Shaded"];
            effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(viewMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(Matrix.Identity);
            effect.Parameters["myTexture"].SetValue(wallTexture);

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                device.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
                device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 12);
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**effect file:**

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;
Texture myTexture;

sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state {
texture = <myTexture>;
MinFilter = Anisotropic; // Minification Filter
MagFilter = Anisotropic; // Magnification Filter
MipFilter = Linear; // Mip-mapping
AddressU = Wrap; // Address Mode for U Coordinates
AddressV = Wrap; // Address Mode for V Coordinates
};


struct VertexShaderInput
{
float4 Position : POSITION0;
float2 UV: TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
float4 Position : POSITION0;
float2 UV: TEXCOORD0;

};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
VertexShaderOutput output;
float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
output.UV = input.UV;

return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
float3 output = float3(1, 1, 1);
output *= tex2D(TextureSampler, input.UV);
return float4(output, 1);
}

technique Shaded
{
pass Pass1
{
VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
}
}
```

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Add yellow to a small area of your texture, and set the (U,V) texture coords of the triangles you want to be yellow to map that area.

**[EDIT]**

Add a Colour channel to your vertex format struct:

**Class**

```
    struct MyVertexFormat
    {
        private Vector3 position;
        private Vector2 texCoord;
        private Color color;
        public MyVertexFormat(Vector3 position, Vector2 texCoord, Color color)
        {
            this.position = position;
            this.texCoord = texCoord;
            this.color = color;
        }

        //Add VertexDeclaration here

    public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = 
        new VertexDeclaration(
            new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
                                 VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3,
                VertexElementFormat.Vector2,
                VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 7,
                VertexElementFormat.Color,
                VertexElementUsage.Color, 0));

            }
```

**Effect**

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 UV: TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Color: Color0;
};
```

As a note, I think is better to inherit your vertex struct from IVertexType.

Comment: that would be cheating i need the colour solution.

Comment: I have tried this already but it throws exception when I try to run. I do have some new ideas to play with draw loop I will post when I will have some time to try it